# e.keychar is not a member of system.eventargs - Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to block my text boxes in order that they can only accept numbers. I was looking in the Internet and I found this code

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) HandlesTextBox1.TextChanged
  If Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) And Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
    e.Handled = True
  End If
End Sub
```

The thing is that there is an error message displayed:

> e.keychar is not a member of system.eventargs

I already imported the `Imports System.EventArgs`. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

I believe the problem lies in the event you’re handling. It should probably not be `TextChanged`. `e.KeyChar` is usually in the `EventArgs` for `KeyPress` handlers. Try using something like `TextBox1_KeyPress`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, i already tried that as well, and still same issue

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
        If e.KeyValue < 48 OrElse e.KeyValue > 57 Then _
            e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to have (sender As Object, e As **KeyPressEventArgs**) 
      which e.KeyChar is a member of